# Where can I find Windows 7 drivers for this laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, acer-aspire, windows-7-restore

I recently bought a laptop, Acer Aspire E5-575G 77ze http://www.acer.com/ac/ro/RO/content/model/NX.GDWEX.055
(http://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.GHGAA.002 I can't find the English site)
My laptop has only drivers for windows 10 and I want to install windows 7 ....what  am I supposed to do for that?
Where I can find them?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, do you have a compelling need to *downgrade* the operating system to Windows 7?  We are always glad to help whenever we can, but as time goes by it will become increasing problematic to find legacy device drivers for brand-new hardware.  Unless there is an extraordinary reason to install Windows 7, it may be prudent to maintain the Windows 10 configuration on that brand-new machine.

Comment: stay at Win10 and mod it to look like Win7: http://superuser.com/a/1140724/174557

Answer (score 0):

This laptop being a new model comes directly with windows 10. So you won't directly get the Windows 7 drivers for your laptop's model on the internet.

Here are the things you can do:

1. After installing windows 7 on this laptop, run a thorough windows update, and let all updates install, this should install all drivers.
2. In case some drivers are not installed, you can get their drivers on the official sites, like chipset (intel), graphics card (Nvidia/AMD), etc.
3. You can also run a driver update using softwares like [Driver Booster](http://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php)

Hope this helps. Cheers :)