# Is my hardware too new for Windows 7? (AMD/FM2 setup)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation

So I have an AMD/FM2 setup here and I'm trying to install Windows 7 on it.

I've tried:

1. UEFI boot
2. standard boot
3. "load optimized default" on BIOS
4. USB2/USB3 ports
5. secure boot: tried Windows and other OS settings. no option to disable.

but the thing doesn't want to boot my USB installer. On UEFI, the setup just goes straight to BIOS settings. On standard, it is somehow working since I can see read activity to the USB stick but it's was just sitting there for like 15 minutes.

I tried the USB installer on an older hardware (LGA1366) and it booted fine.

Perhaps my hardware is too new for Windows 7?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As you are installing Windows 7, try disabling secure boot.

Comment: cannot disable it. can only set it to Windows and Other OS.

Comment: What is the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: @mrjayviper Are you sure you can't disable it? Not even with the in non-UEFI mode?

Comment: Every motherboard doesn't allow secure boot to be disabled. If his doesn't then he's not going to be able to boot Windows 7 even if he is able to install it.

Comment: What motherboard?

Comment: if you can't disable secure boot you're out of luck. But you [can tweak](https://superuser.com/a/1140724/174557) Windows 10 to look like Windows 7 and get Aero and Win7 startmenu back.

Comment: I have to say that it is HIGHLY unlikely that your hardware is "too new" for Windows 7. Heck, you could install MS-DOS on some newer hardware. There's videos all over the internet about it. Have you checked the integrity of the image? Corruption is a possibility, or a bad write to your install media. Maybe something got corrupted that won't let your specific hardware boot off it? Try downloading Windows 7 again, and try writing another installation. If that doesn't work, try booting off a CD/DVD rather than USB, as sometimes that may help.

Comment: Set it to Other OS... The "Windows" settings assumes EFI compatible OS, the Other OS settings is for traditional operating systems, such as Windows 7.